# JavaScript determine number of arguments a function takes

Tags: javascript

Say I have some functions stored in an array of objects, each takes a variable amount of arguments:

```
var ops = [
   {
      id: "plus",
      op: function(a, b) {
         return a + b;
      }
   },
   {
      id: "inverse",
      op: function(a) {
         return -a;
      }
   }
];
```

How would I determine the number of arguments the function takes from outside the function (Without specifying it as an additional property) e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
   var op = ops[i].op;
   var args = ? // Determine number of arguments op takes here
}
```

Is this even possible? If so how?

Comment: You can find the argument count using the length function on the function itself.

Comment: Just remember that `fn.length` is really giving you the number of named parameters whereas in _JavaScript_, you don't always have to pass all of these, and you can pass additional ones which are then accessed through the `arguments` object available inside a _function_ scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use [function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I should of been able to Google that. Something's up with my Google-fu today

Comment: np - for future google purposes, the name for the number of arguments a function expects is "arity".

Comment: @GeorgeReith You might want to use [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) to access `length` avoiding `arguments.callee`.

Comment: @bfavaretto I believe this does the same thing as you are just accessing a property on the function object and not the `arguments` local object which doesn't exist in this scope.

Comment: @GeorgeReith I misunderstood the question, once you have a reference to the function you can access length directly; I though you wanted to get the length from *inside* the anonymous functions.

Comment: @GeorgeReith you should accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Triptych Was just waiting for the timer to ping :P